# Divs stack each other upon zoom

Tags: html, css, zooming

I'm building a website in HTML/CSS, but I'm having an issue. I have 2 divs, one which floats left, and one which floats right. It looks fine on normal zoom in my browser, but when I zoom in, the divs go on top of one another. How can I fix it so they don't do that?

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #336699;
}

.left {
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    background-color: #999999;
}

.right {
    width:750px;
    height:500px;
    float:right;
    background-color: #999999;
}
```

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Time to start looking into responsive layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears because your divs have static widths... combined they both add up to 950px...so on resolutions lower than 950px they will overlap. To fix this you should give them widths in percentages

for example

```
.left{
 width:20%;
}

.right{
 width:75%;
}
```

in this case they will always take 20% and 75% of the current resolution and not overlap.

or if u want them to keep their original widths, you should remove the float property and consider using `display:inline-block` for both of them with a margin between.

Comment: Is there some sort of way to calculator the correct percentage? Such as pixels to percentage

Comment: Check this JSfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/a0u5vh8u/ The way to calculate pixels to percentage is as follows: `100*width of div/width of body`. So to calculate 200 px, you do 100*200/960, resulting in 20.83%

Answer (score 0):

i have convert exact px to percentage value.

```
.left{
 width:20.8%;
}

.right{
 width:78.1%;
}
```